# Is it possible to create Uber-like apps on MIT App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

Currently I do have final project for my bachelor degree ( I am not taking computer science/software engineering major tho ). The project is to create an uber-like app, not for taxi, but to rent agricultural machinery and appliances/services.

Basically, they (those who give me this assignment) expect that the app run like Uber, without knowing how Uber works. They just thought it will be as "simple" as Uber.

Do you think it's possible to create apps using app inventor to cover all basic features of Uber (geolocation, push notification, payment, registration, price calculator, and rating system)? Or should I stick with Android Studio??

My knowledge skill regarding programming is minimal. I do learn about Visual Basic, and I also view several videos on Youtube regarding programming tutorial. Plus, I also learn basic of Java at SoloLearn application.

Final note. I only have less than 4 months to create this app.

Comment: Regardless of what you use I think this is an unrealistic project for a new programmer to do in 4 months.

Comment: @greg-449 i know. But I didnt do it alone. It is a team consisting of 3. And we did not plan to launch this app or turn it into real business. It's just a "working prototype" that i need to show to the professors. After that, boom.... i graduate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an app like Uber on MIT App Inventor. ***MIT App Inventor*** is just for them who just want to enter the line of programming Android Apps. Apps like Uber require high programming skills, large and obviously secure too servers to store user data, which is not possible with ***MIT App Inventor*** .